# LookupSet function referring to entire data source and not following table grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have the following information coming through in my data set -

[image]

I have it linked to a data table that is grouped by **cust_code** and **site_id**

I have a lookup set function in that table, with the goal being retrieval of all **child_id** for a given **site_id** in a table already grouped by **cust_code**.

[image]

However, the lookup set function points to the dataset as a whole, ungrouped, and instead is returning all **child_id**.

[image]

So basically, in this example, I am looking up based on '55' and it is returning all values assosciated to '55', rather than just the '55' value associated with that particular customer.

How can I get the lookup set function to follow the same grouping as the table cell it resides in?

Comment: I seemed to have answered my own question and fixed the problem, but not in a way I am thrilled with. I was able to change the lookup first two parameters of the lookup set function to be a combination of cust_code and site_id by using +. It works, but there has to be a better way...

Comment: That's the correct way to do it, you have to create a unique 'key' to lookup against as you have done.